# How do I create a functional array represented by a binary tree with standard ML?

Tags: arrays, recursion, functional-programming, binary-tree, sml

I am trying to create a functional array using a list, with a given function from a question. **Formally, the task is to create a functional array from a list with indices starting from 1.**

However, I am stuck in this task for days without any progress. Hoping for some hints to get this done..

Here is what I have done:

```
datatype 'a tree = Leaf 
                 | Branch of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree

fun addnode a Leaf = Branch (a, Leaf, Leaf)
      | addnode a (Branch (b, tree1, tree2)) = Branch (a, addnode b tree2, tree1);

fun functionalarray (0, a) = Leaf
    | functionalarray(n, a::b::r) = Branch(a, functionalarray(n div 2, r), functionalarray(n-1 div 2, b::r));
```

where `addnode` is the given function from the question. But I cannot think of a way to use this function. Also, I do not know why my solution doesn't work....

I imagine if I have to use the given function, I would need to perform `n mod 2` such that if n is even, then I need to recursively call `functionalarray` to create a new branch on the left, and if `n mod 2 = 1` and n is odd, then I create a new branch on the right. However, if I do this, then I do not know what to place on the left or right of the branch. For example, I could call something like

```
if n mod 2 = 0 then Branch(a, functionalarray(n div 2, r), ...
```

but I won't be using addnode and I don't know what I should put on the right of the branch.

Any help is very, very appreciated...

Comment: The definition of `addnode` seems weird to me. You mention "the question" a few times; I assume this is a homework problem? Could you post the full thing?

Comment: The problem description is actually very short, which I have written in bold. I've also added the definition of the binary tree to clarify the existence of `addnode`.

Comment: I don't get it. You say that "`addnode` is the given function from the question"; but the problem description doesn't say anything about it. What am I missing?

Comment: The question didn't specify that you must use that function, but it says that there is an elegant solution from using this function. I have done further research and found that this is actually a braun tree structure, which apparently has a "elegant solution" with O(n) time complexity, but I can't make sense of the pseudo code since ML uses linked lists (for the record, I don't really get what is `foldr` etc.): https://www.eecs.northwestern.edu/~robby/courses/395-495-2013-fall/three-algorithms-on-braun-trees.pdf

Comment: Re: "[The question] says that there is an elegant solution from using this function": Eh? You said that the entire problem description is "Formally, the task is to create a functional array from a list with indices starting from 1." Which part of that says anything about this function, or about an elegant solution?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. The question itself was rather disjointed, so I cited the main question only. As mentioned, that extra function is supposed to help you get a elegant solution (as explained by instructors), but it is not entirely necessary to use it at all. The function is not listed in the question formally, but rather given on the side as a hint (handwritten down). But that is really the entirety of the question, and no further information can be extracted.

Comment: My issue is that the problem seems underspecified from what you've posted; there are multiple ways that a binary tree might be used to represent a sort of "array", and it's not clear at all what your requirements are. For example -- can you just call `addnode` repeatedly to append the last element, and then say that your array is represented by whatever arrangement of nodes results from doing that? If not, why not? That's why I think there's more information than you've posted.

Comment: I think what the question really wants is a functional array, which means the tree is a very balanced one in height. Upon checking, I believe this is the implementation of a braun tree. So the question is probably asking to implement a braun tree from a list.

Comment: Re: "a functional array, which means the tree is a very balanced one in height": But it must mean more than that. The only operations I'd expect from an "array" are `getLength : 'a array -> int`, `get : 'a array * int -> 'a`, and `set : 'a array *int * 'a -> 'a array`. It makes sense to implement that as a Braun tree, but the `addnode` seems unnecessary . . . unless there are other operations needed (such as `append : 'a array * 'a -> 'a array`), in which case those should be specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addnode` function inserts a new element at the leftmost position in the tree, i.e., as the first element of the array it represents. By doing so, all existing elements are effectively shifted up one index in the resulting array. So all you need to do is iterate over the input list from right to left and apply `addnode` for each element, starting with an empty array. Hint: this is a one-liner with `List.foldr`.

Of course, the question is odd in the sense that this approach inevitably creates a degenerate tree that is as unbalanced as it can get, and hence no more efficient than using a plain list to represent the array.

Comment: I think you've overlooked that `addnode` swaps the order of the two subtrees. (Which is really weird; I can't make sense of it.)

Comment: I think the criteria is to create a functional array, which is possibly a balanced tree? I found related resources here: https://www.eecs.northwestern.edu/~robby/courses/395-495-2013-fall/three-algorithms-on-braun-trees.pdf but I can't make sense of what it is saying unfortunately (many weird syntaxes).